# Why do I need to put sort on uniq to remove repeated lines?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, uniq

I want to see unique lines of a file (lines that appears only once) but the following command shows repeated lines:

```
uniq -u data.txt 
#(it shows repeated lines)
```

I searched and I found out that if you put `sort` it works, but why ?

```
sort data.txt | uniq - u 
#(it works, only shows unique lines)
```

Comment: Because that's how `uniq` works.

Comment: It says so right in the mage page: `Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent. You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.`

Comment: The description for sort is often worded "omit repeated lines", but it should be "omit consecutive repeated lines".  It does not print a line if it matches the line that was last printed, but doesn't maintain state for more than that.

Comment: BTW, the usual solution is `awk '!a[$0]++' input-file`

Answer (score 3):

It is explicit in the man page:

> Repeated lines in the input will not be detected if they are not adja-
>        cent, so it may be necessary to sort the files first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
sort -u uniqtest
```

ex:

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat uniqtest 
aaaa
aaaa
bbbb
bbbb
a
b
c
d
user@host/tmp$ sort -u uniqtest 
a
aaaa
b
bbbb
c
d
```

From uniq method manual;

```
...
 Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'. 
....
```